# PHP show "open / save" dialog

Tags: php, excel, file, csv, savefiledialog

I'm using PHP to generate an Excel file through CSV. I'm using a very simple piece of code to prepare the whole function before filling it with my own data:

```
$list = array (
  array('#', 'Registrar', 'Country', 'Website', 'Email Address'),
  array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
  array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
);

$fp = fopen('myfile.xls', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", '"');
}

fclose($fp);
```

The code works fine. However, it automatically saves "myfile.xls" to the directory where the PHP file is executed. I want the page to show the "open / save" dialog to let the user chose where he/she wants to save the file. I've tried some header tricks like these:

```
header ("Content-Type: application/download");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.xls");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize(myfile.xls));
```

However, when using this, the exported file shows the page content (which includes a header with a title, a menu, a footer, etc.) instead of the data in the "list" variable... I can't prevent the header nor the footer to be included in the PHP page as it's part of a framework, so I simply want to choose where the "myfile.xls" generated through the PHP's CSV function is stored.

I've also considered and tried using PHPExcel and other packages intended to generate an Excel, but I'm unable to get any of them working properly. I've lost too many days trying it, so I've decided to simply create a CSV file, which is OK for my purposes. The only thing I need now is the "open / save" dialog and it'll be perfect for me.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Comment: Most frameworks provide some mechanism allowing you to suppress their own headers and use your own instead, so what framework are you using?

Comment: Hi Mark! I'm using Yii Framework, which always "embeds" its pages inside the framework, showing the header, the menu and the footer...

Comment: I'm not an expert on frameworks, but there must surely be some method built into Yii that suppresses its own headers allowing you to override them with custom headers: e.g. for serving non-html data (http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7522-http-headers-simple-question/)

Comment: Hi Mark, and thanks for your time! I've found a method within the framework that does what you say (though I haven't implemented it yet because it isn't that easy to use). However, I think there should be a simplest way to show the dialog for the file I'm actually generating: the "myfile.xls" is generated and saved in the root directory of my PHP script, and I simply want to browser to ask me "where do you want to store this file?"... Isn't there an easiest way to do so?

Comment: That all comes down to the headers you send to the browser; and using `php://output` as your filename... the same applies whether you're using PHPExcel, a simple csv (as you're doing), PDFs, images and mpegs, anything that you want to create and send directly to the browser

Comment: Well, I've found a way of doing so by avoiding header, menu and footer to appear (as you said)... It took me an entire morning to figure out how to do, but now I think I'll be able to get it working. Thanks, Mark! :)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$file = "location of file to download"
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Comment: Hi Vishal! I've tried your code but I can't get it work... I've pasted it before and after my code (changing "$file" for "$fp", which is my file variable) but it behaves weirdly: the page shows a kind of 404 error as if it can't find the file... Commenting the two lines where the $file variable appears makes the page opening a download dialog of the PHP file. However, I can't make the code download my XLS file, as it shows that "can't find the PHP page you are executing" error... Strange... :S

Comment: try giving full path for file to be downloaded

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding it well, but the file to be downloaded is generated in the PHP script itself, so I can't give its full path... The PHP generates a new XLS file and I want to user to choose whether to open or download the newly created file.